# Как подключить PostgreSQL с нуля

Tags: c++, sql, windows, postgresql

Я знаю что `PostgreSQL` довольно хорошая, быстрая и надежная. Но вот как бы мне подключиться на `С++` к базе данных с нуля?

Что нужно устанавливать?
 Как настроить?
 Какая библиотека С++ для подключения?

Допустим `SQLite(я использовал только в python django)` это просто `один файл`. Но я сомневаюсь, что `postresql` тоже просто 1 файл. Ну вообщем, как мне настроить базу данных на `postgreSQL` локально(можно так же сказать как это потом на просторы интернета залить, но не обязательно). И как подключится через `С++` к ней. Ну и выполнять запросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Где его взять** - [на официальном сайте](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/).

Для разработки, пожалуй, может оказаться удобным не ставить его как сервис, а просто качнуть [архив с бинарниками](https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries). В архиве есть батники для запуска и остановки сервера.

Как настроить - да никак, для использования в одну каску он готов к употреблению.
Кроме постгреса вам может понадобится [pgadmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/) (Или любой другой его аналог). Это **инструмент администрирования**, он работает через веб-браузер. Настройка там тривиальна:

```
Хост localhost
Пользователь postgres
Пароль пустой
База postgres
```

**Клиентская библиотека** называется [libpq](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/10/libpq)

[Примеры кода](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-example.html)

```
* testlibpq.c
 *
 *      Test the C version of libpq, the PostgreSQL frontend library.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>

static void
exit_nicely(PGconn *conn)
{
    PQfinish(conn);
    exit(1);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *conninfo;
    PGconn     *conn;
    PGresult   *res;
    int         nFields;
    int         i,
                j;

    /*
     * If the user supplies a parameter on the command line, use it as the
     * conninfo string; otherwise default to setting dbname=postgres and using
     * environment variables or defaults for all other connection parameters.
     */
    if (argc > 1)
        conninfo = argv[1];
    else
        conninfo = "dbname = postgres";

    /* Make a connection to the database */
    conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);

    /* Check to see that the backend connection was successfully made */
    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s",
                PQerrorMessage(conn));
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    /*
     * Our test case here involves using a cursor, for which we must be inside
     * a transaction block.  We could do the whole thing with a single
     * PQexec() of "select * from pg_database", but that's too trivial to make
     * a good example.
     */

    /* Start a transaction block */
    res = PQexec(conn, "BEGIN");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BEGIN command failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    /*
     * Should PQclear PGresult whenever it is no longer needed to avoid memory
     * leaks
     */
    PQclear(res);

    /*
     * Fetch rows from pg_database, the system catalog of databases
     */
    res = PQexec(conn, "DECLARE myportal CURSOR FOR select * from pg_database");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_COMMAND_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "DECLARE CURSOR failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }
    PQclear(res);

    res = PQexec(conn, "FETCH ALL in myportal");
    if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "FETCH ALL failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQclear(res);
        exit_nicely(conn);
    }

    /* first, print out the attribute names */
    nFields = PQnfields(res);
    for (i = 0; i < nFields; i++)
        printf("%-15s", PQfname(res, i));
    printf("\n\n");

    /* next, print out the rows */
    for (i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < nFields; j++)
            printf("%-15s", PQgetvalue(res, i, j));
        printf("\n");
    }

    PQclear(res);

    /* close the portal ... we don't bother to check for errors ... */
    res = PQexec(conn, "CLOSE myportal");
    PQclear(res);

    /* end the transaction */
    res = PQexec(conn, "END");
    PQclear(res);

    /* close the connection to the database and cleanup */
    PQfinish(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pgadmin4 обязательно? У меня просто есть программа jetbrains DataGrip. Или это не то?

Comment: Да пойдет любая тулза для администрирования, я ж не знал, что она у вас есть.

Comment: Извините, а база данных postgres это - база по умолчанию? Создать новую можно, верно?

Comment: @Данил да, вы все понимаете верно. И про базу по-умолчанию, и про возможность создания других баз.